# Why is S.T.A.R. labs so easy to walk into?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Several characters including villains just walk into where Barry is in his Flash suit unmasked, or testing his speed in street clothes.

Comment: because Barry is secretly on a mission to tell everyone who he is.

Comment: I would like to know this answer too. It seems like there is no lock on the door. People just come walking in at the perfect time during a conversation.

Comment: They also make a joke about this on the Flash-Arrow crossover event, when Oliver says they can't go hide in S.T.A.R. labs because of the "revolving doors" they installed so anyone can get in/

Answer (score 2):

**It is hopelessly understaffed and was never originally designed for security.**

Star Labs is a huge facility that only ever has 2-3 people permanently around. Even after Cisco "upgrades" security to prevent people from just 'walking in', in that same episode someone just walks in and by passes what I can only assume was a stern 'do not enter' sign.

This suggests two things:

1. for all of Cisco's brilliance, he is a terrible installer of security systems.
2. It isn't easy for a few people and cameras to cover all the entrances of a large research facility that wasn't necessarily designed for security.